# IE7 expression not equal to table-cell height

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm vertically centering multi-lined text with my code. It works in all modern browsers, but not in IE7. I searched around and found me a CSS expression on CSS-Tricks that should fix it.

Unfortunately the height of the element in IE7 is not `107px`, it appears to be bigger. I just found out about CSS expressions and have little knowledge about it.

Could anybody indicate the problem and solution?

**CSS**

```
p.caption {
    display: table-cell; 
    height: 107px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #868686;
    text-align: center;  
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**IE7 CSS**

```
p.caption {
    clear: expression(
        style.marginTop = "" + (offsetHeight < parentNode.offsetHeight ? parseInt((parentNode.offsetHeight - offsetHeight) / 2) + "px" : "0"),
        style.clear = "none", 0
    );
}
```

**Live example:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uU75r/4/)

*I don't think JSFiddle supports IE expressions?*

Comment: Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: cant you use another css which target only IE7 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add height: 107px; to 'div' but not 'p'

```
div#fullWidth{
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
  background: #dddddd;
  height: 107px;
}

p.caption{
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

display: table-cell is not supported on IE7. So vertical-align is not applied. See there:

http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

http://www.kamui.co.uk/2012/01/23/css-display-table-cell-table-row-table-in-ie7/

This bypass seems to work (tested on IE7/8 & FF25):

**CSS:**

```
div#fullWidth {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    background: #dddddd;
    height: 107px;
}

p.caption {
    display: table-cell; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #868686;
    text-align: center;  
    vertical-align: middle;
    _margin-top: expression((parentNode.offsetHeight.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) <0 ? "0":(parentNode.offsetHeight/2)-(parseInt(this.offsetHeight)/2) +'px');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fullWidth">
    <p class="caption">Testing 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10</p>
</div>
```

The "_" in the CSS is another bypass taken into account only by IE (not sure for IE9 & 10). FF, Chrome and Opera will ignore it.

Be careful on height: it is defined on parent element size. As always on IE, an element size is applied if all its parents height (or width) are set.

```
_height: 100%;
_width: 100%;
```

can be useful.